# Reporting a correlation matrix in APA style

Tags: correlation, reporting

If you are reporting a correlation matrix in APA style, are you supposed to report `r` as in `corr.test()` or `R^2` as in `lm()$r.squared`? Which one is correct, and what does the other one represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APA publication manual does not explicitly say weather you should choose $R^2$ or $r$ for your results. They say however:

*Page 38 of APA Manual*:

> When reporting the results of inferential statistical tests or when
>   providing estimates of parameters or effect sizes, include sufficient
>   information to help the reader fully understand the analyses conducted
>   and possible alternative explanations for the outcomes of those
>   analyses. Because each analytic technique depends on different aspects
>   of the data and assumptions, it is impossible to specify what
>   constitutes a "sufficient set of statistics" for every analysis.
>   However, such a set usually includes at least the following: the
>   per-cell sample sizes; the observed cell means (or frequencies of
>   cases in each category for a categorical variable); and the cell
>   standard deviations, or the pooled within-cell variance. In the case
>   of multivariable analytic systems, such as multivariate analyses of
>   variance, regression analyses, structural equation modeling analyses,
>   and hierarchical linear modeling, the associated means, sample sizes,
>   and variance-covariance (or correlation) matrix or matrices often
>   represent a sufficient set of statistics. At times, the amount of
>   information that constitutes a sufficient set of statistics can be
>   extensive; when this is the case, this information could be supplied
>   in a supplementary data set or appendix.

The only place with a correlation table is page 136 with this example:

[image]

That being said, I would report *Person rs* with *p* values for showing correlation results and leave $R^2s$ for regression results